# MySQL PHP update another table based on entered results

Tags: php, mysql

Using MySQL and PHP I have created a local website that allows me to input the results of a fixture that hasn't yet been entered i.e. I can select a fixture without a result from a  list, the team names appear i.e. "Team A vs. Team B" and I enter the score and it saves to result table successfully.

However, I'm unsure how to update the Team table stats:

e.g. if I enter that Team 3 beat Team 4 *2-0*, the following should happen:

Team 3 played + 1, won +1, gf+2, gd+2, points+3

AND
 Team 4 played + 1, lost +1, ga+2, gd-2

**Fixture Table**

```
| fixture_id | home_team | away_team |

     | 1 |      | 1 |        | 4 |
     | 2 |      | 2 |        | 3 |
     | 3 |      | 4 |        | 3 |
```

**Result Table**

```
Result_ID | Fixture_ID | Home_Goals | Away_Goals |

     | 1 |     | 1 |        | 2 |        | 0 |    i.e home team wins 2-0.
     | 2 |     | 2 |        | 2 |        | 2 |
```

**Team Table**

```
team_id | team_name | played | won  | drawn | lost | gf   | ga   | gd   | points |

     |  3 | Team 3   |   37  | 30 |   6  |  2 |95 |22 |73| 96 |
     |  4 | Team 4   |   37  | 27 |   7  |  4 |104|40 |64| 88 |
```

How do I code this in PHP & MySQL?

Thank you.

**addResult.php**

```
<form method="POST" id="selectFixture">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <?php


                echo '<td> <select name ="fixture_id">';    

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT  f.*, t1.Team_Name AS Home, t2.Team_Name AS Away
                                        FROM Fixture        f
                                        INNER JOIN Team     t1 ON f.Home_Team = t1.Team_ID
                                        INNER JOIN Team     t2 ON f.Away_Team = t2.Team_ID
                                        LEFT JOIN Result    r ON f.Fixture_ID = r.Fixture_ID
                                        WHERE r.Result_ID IS NULL');

                $stmt->execute();
                foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['Fixture_ID'] . '">' . $row['Home'] . ' v ' .  $row['Away'] . '</option>';
                }  

                ?>  
            </select> 
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Home Team Goals: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="homeG"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Away Team Goals: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="awayG"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>Submit</button>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $result = [
             'Fixture_ID' => $_POST['fixture_id'],
             'Home_Goals' => $_POST['homeG'],
             'Away_Goals' => $_POST['awayG'],         
    ];  

    insert($pdo, 'Result', $result);
    echo 'Result added.'; 
    header("Refresh:0");
}


function insert($pdo, $table, $record)
{

    $keys = array_keys($record);

    $values = implode(', ', $keys);
    $valuesWithColon = implode(', :', $keys);

    $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (' . $values . ') VALUES (:' . $valuesWithColon . ')'; 

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute($record);
}
```

Comment: this is far too broad for SO's question style. The normally accepted format is to show what youv'e written so far and explain where you're stuck. People won't generally code you something on this scale from nothing. Have you got _any_ code at all? Have you ever done anything in PHP/MySQL before? If so, do you understand the basics of connecting to a DB, making SQL queries etc? We really have no idea how much help you need, or which aspects of this solution are a problem for you.

Comment: I've added my code so far.

Comment: The problem is I insert a result but I want to update the Team table to manipulate the stats by the result i.e. if a team wins 5-0, played=played+1, wins=wins+1, points=point+3 etc. and the reverse for the losing team.

Comment: So what's the problem? Just do an `UPDATE` query that makes those changes.

Comment: That is what I am asking, i'm stuck on the UPDATE query.

Comment: What are `gd`, `ga`, `gf`, and `points`? I don't understand how they come from the results.

Comment: I think I figured some of them: `gf` = goals for this team, `ga` = goals against this team, `gd` = goal difference (ga - gd). But I still don't understand `points`.

Comment: correct and point i.e. a win = 3points, draw = 1point, loss = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the `UPDATE` query you need.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $result = [
             'Fixture_ID' => $_POST['fixture_id'],
             'Home_Goals' => $_POST['homeG'],
             'Away_Goals' => $_POST['awayG'],         
    ];  

    insert($pdo, 'Result', $result);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
        UPDATE Fixture AS f
        JOIN Team AS t1 ON f.Home_Team = t1.Team_ID
        JOIN Team AS t2 ON f.Away_Team = t2.Team_ID
        SET t1.played = t1.played + 1,
            t1.won = IF(:Home_Goals > :Away_Goals, t1.won + 1, t1.won),
            t1.drawn = IF(:Home_Goals = :Away_Goals, t1.drawn + 1, t1.drawn),
            t1.lost = IF(:Home_Goals < :Away_Goals, t1.lost + 1, t1.lost),
            t1.gf = t1.gf + :Home_Goals,
            t1.ga = t1.ga + :Away_Goals,
            t1.gd = t1.gd + :Home_Goals - :Away_Goals,
            t1.points = t1.points + 
                CASE WHEN :Home_Goals > :Away_Goals THEN 3
                     WHEN :Home_Goals = :Away_Goals THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                END,
            t2.played = t2.played + 1,
            t2.won = IF(:Away_Goals > :Home_Goals, t2.won + 1, t2.won),
            t2.drawn = IF(:Away_Goals = :Home_Goals, t2.drawn + 1, t2.drawn),
            t2.lost = IF(:Away_Goals < :Home_Goals, t2.lost + 1, t2.lost),
            t2.gf = t2.gf + :Away_Goals,
            t2.ga = t2.ga + :Home_Goals,
            t2.gd = t2.gd + :Away_Goals - :Home_Goals,
            t2.points = t2.points +
                CASE WHEN :Away_Goals > :Home_Goals THEN 3
                     WHEN :Away_Goals = :Home_Goals THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                END
        WHERE f.Fixture_ID = :Fixture_id');
    $stmt->execute($result);
    echo 'Result added.'; 
    header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Comment: Before or after you call `insert()`.